# Generate js variable before javascript loaded

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a block with invocation code inside(it invokes js code from OpenX ads server), my site is responsive and this block get cloned(with `jquery .clone()` function) on ipad or iphone version of the site. So to avoid calling the invocation js code 2 times i need to set js variable (like this - > `window.isScriptLoaded = FALSE`) and then inside my block i can easy do next thing:

```
if (window.isScriptLoaded == FALSE) {
    window.isScriptLoaded = TRUE;
    //invocation code...
}
```

in this case all working fine, i can easy add this variable to any js file in drupal.

But in my case `admin` can add new block and insert new invocation code - SO I need to generate `window.isScriptLoaded2` and **output this variable BEFORE code in block is loaded**

i tried next thing

```
function HOOK_page_alter(&$page) {
  //get all the variables
  //i generate my variables in database
  $var = db_query("SELECT * FROM {banners}")->fetchAll();
     $full_array = array();
     foreach($var as $object) {
         //for example Anyvariable = FALSE;
         $array[$object->name] = $object->value;
     }
      drupal_add_js(array('common' => array(
    'vars' => $array,
    )), 'setting');

}
```

this works but, code in block is loaded before `drupal.settings.vars.Anyvariable` is loaded.
So my variables is always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also hard to say if this will work without seeing exactly what you need to do, but you may want to play with the scope, group, and weight options for [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).  These may help you get the order that you need.  From the docs

> The exact ordering of JavaScript is as follows:
>
> - First by scope, with 'header' first, 'footer' last, and any other scopes provided by a custom theme coming in between, as determined by
>     the theme.
> - Then by group.
> - Then by the 'every_page' flag, with TRUE coming before FALSE.
> - Then by weight.
> - Then by the order in which the JavaScript was added. For example, all else being the same, JavaScript added by a call to drupal_add_js()
>     that happened later in the page request gets added to the page after
>     one for which drupal_add_js() happened earlier in the page request.

When I have been in similar situations, I implement a [`template_preprocess_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7), create some markup, stuff it into `$variables`, and then output this before the `print $scripts` in html.tpl.php  I have to use this in some very specific situations where I need to output JS very early in the `<head>` before CSS and JS is loaded.

Comment: oh my god, this task is pissed me off, thank you (^_^;) i generated variable in `preprocess_html` and used it before `$scripts` ITS `TRUE` u made my day <3